# How to display a video with a transparent/masked background?

Tags: android, android-videoview, textureview

The wording on this is most likely wrong, but I want to play [this](http://media-Hearth.cursecdn.com/goldCards/0/503/503.webm) video without having the background black. If you look at [this](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/503-ragnaros-the-firelord) webpage you will see that the video is on a white background which leads me to believe that it is cropped or masked. Which view would I use to do this? I have tried both TextureView and VideoView but both have a black background by default.

Comment: Could it be this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video?hl=en

Comment: This is definitely the correct definition of what I want to do, but unfortunately this is only relating to chrome and only regarding the filming and encoding of such videos.

Comment: Do you find a solution ?

Answer (score -2):

**I solve it with this:**

```
  @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onInfo, what = " + what);
        if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START) {
          // video started; hide the placeholder.
          placeholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
```

I think **onPrepared** just means the video is ready to play, but not means video started playing. If hide placeholder in **onPrepared**, the screen still show a black screen.

On my Note4 and Nexus, this solution works well.

Comment: This results in the view being hidden completely.

Comment: placeholder.setVisibility(View.GONE); What is placeholder? If it is TextureView then he is hidden completely, not masked background.